# Change JSO(N) parameters that have been set by another module

Tags: 6, javascript

I am trying to override parameters that have been set by another module. The other module uses `drupal_add_js()` to set the parameters.

```
 $settings = array('color'=>'red','type' =>'round');
 drupal_add_js(array('MyData'=>$settings),'setting'));
```

This adds a JavaScript object to the `drupal.settings` data object. I want to override that in another module, and I don't know how. It seems to always "ADD" to the array and NOT override it.

The following code doesn't work.

```
$js = drupal_add_js(null,'setting'); //<-- get the JS
unset($js['setting'][1]['MyData']['color']);
drupal_add_js($js,'setting');
```

```
 $settings = array('color'=>'PINK'); // <- Change red to pink
 drupal_add_js(array('MyData'=>$settings),'setting'));
```

How can I do what I am trying?

Comment: could you use 'inline' and change the settings or is that too late?

Comment: You could set your own settings and copy the values on the pre-existing settings set by the other module in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
// Get all the current javascript information
$current_js = drupal_add_js(NULL, NULL, 'header');

// Filter the information down to just the settings.
$current_js_settings = $current_js['setting'];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is using code similar to the following one in your module.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $javascript = drupal_add_js(NULL, NULL, 'setting');

  foreach ($javascript as $index => $array) {
    if (isset($array['MyData'])) {
      $array['MyData'] = /* Change the array values. */;
    }
  }

  $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', array('setting' => $javascript));
}
```

In Drupal 7, altering the JavaScript code added from another module is done implementing [hook_js_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another way,

Lets consider original data is available in Drupal.settings.myData.

Now set your custom data in different place say Drupal.settings.custom.myData, then use the following JavaScript code to merge those values,

```
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings.mydata, Drupal.settings.custom.myData, true);
Drupal.attachBehaviors();
```

Include these lines in your custom JavaScript function, attachBehaviours take care of applying these new settings :)

I'm using this when I have to deal with lot of ajax requests in the page.

Comment: why the merge? why not simply keep them separate and search for you specific data under `Drupal.settings.custom.myData`?

Answer (score 0):

If using Drupal 6 you can use the [AdvAgg module](http://drupal.org/project/advagg) to do what you need. It provides hooks that allow you to alter js before it is pushed out into HTML. Here is an example of how to overwrite JS using advagg in Drupal 6: http://drupal.org/node/231451#comment-6574710. Note that is is changing inline code not the settings, but changing the settings should be fairly straight forward.